# measuring adjacency between polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, arcgis-10.2, topology

I am working with some land ownership data. I would like to identify parcels the have small adjacency between other parcels.

In a nutshell I want to identify where there is a small overlap between sections. In the example below you can see where one section overlaps another by a small amount of about 15 meters. In most situations this value of overlap is zero.

[image]

Any suggestions how I can detect these situations? I am on arc 10.2 with Spatial Analyst.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the 'Polygon Neighbors' tool from ArcToolBox.

[image]

Ensure that 'Include area overlaps' is checked.

[image]

It will create a table showing you the neighbours polygons and if they overlap (including area), share a common line (including length) or point (number of touching points).